# Why do I get a list as the final output of the sorted() function when sorting a tuple?

Tags: python, tuples

I've got a very stupid question, I am learning Python and I was wondering why when I sort a tuple using the `sorted()` function the output I get is of a list type rather than a tuple, is this related to the fact that tuples are immutable, and is there a way to obtain a tuple as the final output?

Comment: Because that is what the function *does*, `sorted` returns a list of sorted items from whatever iterable you pass in. Did you check the documentation? "is this related to the fact that tuples are immutable" no, that's irrelevant. If you want a tuple, you can just use the `tuple `constructor, `tuple(sorted(original_data))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that you get a list as a result of sorting of a tuple is not related to the fact that tuples are immutable. Actually, `sorted` returns a list as a result for any iterables:

```
>>> sorted({'a': 1, 'b': 2})  # mutable
['a', 'b']
>>> sorted({3, 2, 1})  # mutable
[1, 2, 3]
>>> sorted('word')  # immutable
['d', 'o', 'r', 'w']
>>> sorted(frozenset({1, 2, 3}))  # immutable
[1, 2, 3]
```

This is explicitly mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted):

> `sorted(iterable, *, key=None, reverse=False)`
>   Return a new sorted ***list*** from the items in iterable.
>   ...

To get a sorted tuple, you would simply write:

```
>>> my_tuple = (2, 1, 3)
>>> sorted_tuple = tuple(sorted(my_tuple))
>>> sorted_tuple
(1, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Python Central](https://www.pythoncentral.io/how-to-sort-a-list-tuple-or-object-with-sorted-in-python/) page gives the following information

> Since tuples are arrays that you cannot modify, they don't have an in-place sort function that can be called directly on them. They must always use the sorted function to return a sorted list.

So simply put, tuples don't have a sorting method because they are immutable, but you can use the sorted() function on tuples. This function will always return a list.

To get a tuple as output you would have to convert it after sorting it:

```
t = (1,2,4,3)
sorted_list = sorted(t)
tuple(sorted_list)
```

will give you a tuple again.

Comment: "the fact they are immutable causes this phenomenon" No, that is not correct. `sorted` simply *always returns a new list object* from an arbitrary iterable. The type of the iterable is irrelevant.